# Upload file causes Aw, Snap on chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

I upload a video (100MB) through the following code:

```
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    reader.onload = function(e) {  
        // get file content  
        var myFile = e.target.result;
        var data = {
            'data':myFile,
            'nome':name_list[i],
            'tipo_campanha':tipo_campanha,
            'tipo':type_list[i],
            'date':date_list[i]
        };
        $scope.campanha_id = 49;
        $http.post(api_url + 'campanha/' + $scope.campanha_id + '/arquivo',data).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                if(length==document.getElementById('filedata').files.length){
                    alert('Upload Done');
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('#arquivo-submit').show();
                    $state.go('home');
               }
             },
             function errorCallback(response) {
                 alert('Error');
                 $('#loader').hide();
                 $('#arquivo-submit').show();
                 console.log(response);
             }
        );
    }
```

When i upload the file on Chrome, i receive the "Aw, Snap!" page. When i upload on Firefox, it works perfectly.

**Informations:**

- The request(POST) appears on the Network(inspect) but the server does not receive it
- Smallest videos work on chrome

**Questions:**

- Is it a bug on Chrome?
- How do i fix it?

Comment: Looks probably a bug in Chrome to handle such large files...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman , do you know any work around?

Comment: try [`ng-file-upload`](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to Upload your files. Also don't use jQuery with AngularJS; DOM manipulations are for directives